# Create shapefile from data PostGIS or KML using Java

Tags: postgis, postgresql, java, export

I'm working on a geographic information system project, whose products form shapefiles. I am using the Java programming language and a PostGIS database. Is there a way to generate a shapefile from PostGIS or KML using the Java language?

Comment: Another thing you could look into is GeoTools.  It is another open source package written in Java.  It may have a little more than what you need, but it would allow you more freedom to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 2):

[Geotools](http://www.geotools.org/) is a powerful library, and can read from PostGIS, [for example](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTOOLS/How+to+use+a+PostGISDataStore), and can export to ShapeFile, [for example](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/feature/csv2shp.html), using the "Feature" object.

I cann't show you a complete "example", but it's easy to find out a way to do it, in Google.

Answer (score 2):

You can use geotools to do such actions. You may find [here](http://freeopengis.blogspot.gr/2015/06/convert-oracle-resultset-to-esri.html) an example converting a java ResultSet to shapefile. Though the example provided is using an oracle ResultSet but you can easily adjust it to accept postgis ResultSet and generate shapefiles.

Answer (score 1):

[H2GIS](http://www.h2gis.org) is a lightweight (about 5 megabytes) embedded spatial database written in Java and available on Maven Central. It could suit your needs. A [short sample](http://github.com/irstv/orbisgis-samples) of using this library is available.

> generate a shp file from PostGIS

[H2GIS](http://www.h2gis.org) can import/export SHP files. You can use the [SHPDriverFunction](https://github.com/irstv/H2GIS/blob/master/h2drivers/src/main/java/org/h2gis/drivers/shp/SHPDriverFunction.java) by providing a JDBC connection with PostGIS.You should use this [connection wrapper](https://github.com/irstv/orbisgis/blob/master/bundles/postgis-jts-osgi/src/main/java/org/orbisgis/postgis_jts_osgi/ConnectionWrapper.java) in order to bind JTS geometry object to postgis geometry object.

> generate a kml file from PostGIS

A [KMLDriverFunction](https://github.com/irstv/H2GIS/blob/master/h2drivers/src/main/java/org/h2gis/drivers/kml/KMLDriverFunction.java) is also available.

Please note that the H2GIS library is under the GPLV3 license. In order to use this your software must be open-source.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for [OpenJUMP](http://www.openjump.org/) it's a GIS Java software, you can use it to display PostGIS files or for developing Plugins.
You can read more about this GIS Java software [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/72-OpenJump-for-PostGIS-Spatial-Ad-Hoc-Queries.html).